# setting tha data array to a initial value after editing that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, methods, reset

Is there a way Vue.js provides setting data array arr to the initial value, after it had being changed with methods ? I've changed the checkboxes and its values and now want to reset the data array to initial state.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Example 1</h1>
    <div
      v-for="(a, i) in arr"
      :key="i"
      :checked="a"
      @click="toggleItem(i)"
      class="checkbox"
    >
      <div class="out">{{ a }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="out">{{ arr }}</div>
    <div class="out">{{ newArr }}</div>
    <!-- <div class="out">{{ newArr }}</div> -->
    <input @click="resetState" type="button" value="Reset" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      arr: [true, false, true, false, true, true, true]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleItem(index) {
      this.arr.splice(index, 1, !this.arr[index]);
    },
    resetState() {
      // set the array arr to initial data after some toggleItem() changes
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to save the default value somewhere else, such as:

```html
<script>
const defaultArr = [true, false, true, false, true, true, true];

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      arr: [...defaultArr]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleItem(index) {
      this.arr.splice(index, 1, !this.arr[index]);
    },
    resetState() {
      // set the array arr to initial data after some toggleItem() changes
      this.arr = [...defaultArr];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

> Note the spreading syntax `[...]` is neccessary since you don't want to mutate the default array.